# How to pass options from Startup.cs to DbContextOptions constructor function at ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0

At Startup.cs I have

```
services.AddDbContext<MailDBServicesContext>(optionsSqLite =>
        {
            optionsSqLite.UseSqlite("Data Source=Mail.db");
        });
```

I have created a model and a DbContext where DbContext is:

```
public class MailDBServicesContext : DbContext
{
    public MailDBServicesContext(DbContextOptions<MailDBServicesContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<MailCountSentErrorMails> DbSetMailCountSentErrorMails { get; set; }
}
```

from a Class helper I need to pass DbContextOptions and my question is how can I tell to use the options from the Startup.cs ConfigureServices method

```
using (var db = new MailDBServicesContext())
                        {
                        }
```

Comment: You do not `new` it. Let the DI inject it for you in your class.

Comment: Sorry Shyju, I don't find how can you please share some code please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be enough to simply inject `MailDBServicesContext` into your controller or a service class, for example.

```
public class SomeDataService
{
    private readonly MailDBServicesContext _dbContext;

    public SomeDataService(MailDBServicesContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
    }

    public async Task AddMailCounts()
    {
        _dbContext.DbSetMailCountSentErrorMails
            .Add(new MailCountSentErrorMails { CountSentMails = 55 });
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Other DB context configuration options are defined in [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) on MSDN.

**Update**

Make sure to register your service in DI, i.e. `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ISomeDataService, SomeDataService>();
    services.AddDbContext<MailDBServicesContext>(optionsSqLite =>
    {
        optionsSqLite.UseSqlite("Data Source=Mail.db");
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Then make a call to `AddMailCounts()` in your controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISomeDataService _dataService;

    public HomeController(ISomeDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataService));
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _dataService.AddMailCounts();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Now every time you load homepage, a record is inserted into `DbSetMailCountSentErrorMails` table.

You can find working solution on my [GitHub](https://github.com/ignas-sakalauskas/AspNetCore2SqliteExample).

Comment: I am receiving the error:
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at TestApp.MyServices.MailClass.<SendErrorEmail>d__1.MoveNext()

when trying to call:
_dbContext.DbSetMailCountSentErrorMails.Add(new MailCountSentErrorMails() {countSentMails = 55});

Comment: I've updated my answer, and included an example on my GitHub. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help, now it is working!

Comment: @AG70 You should mark Ignas's answer as the answer to the question by clicking the checkmark under the up and down vote buttons.